# Yulio Raytracer compilation errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, virtual-reality

I was trying to use Yuilo Raytracer renderer, but I got some build errors during the build. Would appreciate suggestions.

https://github.com/YulioTech/Yulio-Raytracer

```
1>------ Build started: Project: image, Configuration: ReleaseAVX x64 ------
1>lodepng.cpp
1>..\..\3rd party\LodePNG\lodepng.cpp(762): warning C4334: '<<': result of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 64 bits (was 64-bit shift intended?)
1>..\..\3rd party\LodePNG\lodepng.cpp(1422): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>..\..\3rd party\LodePNG\lodepng.cpp(1426): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>..\..\3rd party\LodePNG\lodepng.cpp(1498): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>..\..\3rd party\LodePNG\lodepng.cpp(3441): warning C4334: '<<': result of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 64 bits (was 64-bit shift intended?)
1>..\..\3rd party\LodePNG\lodepng.cpp(3455): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>..\..\3rd party\LodePNG\lodepng.cpp(4262): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>..\..\3rd party\LodePNG\lodepng.cpp(4310): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>..\..\3rd party\LodePNG\lodepng.cpp(4390): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>..\..\3rd party\LodePNG\lodepng.cpp(5329): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>devil.cpp
1>exr.cpp
1>freeimage.cpp
1>C:\Users\Surya\Desktop\Yulio-Raytracer-master\Yulio-Raytracer-master\common\image/image.h(2): error C2059: syntax error: '.'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\surya\desktop\yulio-raytracer-master\yulio-raytracer-master\common\math\../simd/sse_special.h(70): warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'const int' requires a narrowing conversion
1>image.cpp
1>c:\users\surya\desktop\yulio-raytracer-master\yulio-raytracer-master\common\image\image.h(2): error C2059: syntax error: '.'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\surya\desktop\yulio-raytracer-master\yulio-raytracer-master\common\math\../simd/sse_special.h(70): warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'const int' requires a narrowing conversion
1>jpeg.cpp
1>C:\Users\Surya\Desktop\Yulio-Raytracer-master\Yulio-Raytracer-master\common\image/image.h(2): error C2059: syntax error: '.'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\surya\desktop\yulio-raytracer-master\yulio-raytracer-master\common\math\../simd/sse_special.h(70): warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'const int' requires a narrowing conversion
1>magick.cpp
1>pfm.cpp
1>C:\Users\Surya\Desktop\Yulio-Raytracer-master\Yulio-Raytracer-master\common\image/image.h(2): error C2059: syntax error: '.'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\surya\desktop\yulio-raytracer-master\yulio-raytracer-master\common\math\../simd/sse_special.h(70): warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'const int' requires a narrowing conversion
1>png.cpp
1>C:\Users\Surya\Desktop\Yulio-Raytracer-master\Yulio-Raytracer-master\common\image/image.h(2): error C2059: syntax error: '.'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\surya\desktop\yulio-raytracer-master\yulio-raytracer-master\common\math\../simd/sse_special.h(70): warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'const int' requires a narrowing conversion
1>ppm.cpp
1>C:\Users\Surya\Desktop\Yulio-Raytracer-master\Yulio-Raytracer-master\common\image/image.h(2): error C2059: syntax error: '.'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\surya\desktop\yulio-raytracer-master\yulio-raytracer-master\common\math\../simd/sse_special.h(70): warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'const int' requires a narrowing conversion
1>tga.cpp
1>C:\Users\Surya\Desktop\Yulio-Raytracer-master\Yulio-Raytracer-master\common\image/image.h(2): error C2059: syntax error: '.'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\sal.h(2361): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\surya\desktop\yulio-raytracer-master\yulio-raytracer-master\common\math\../simd/sse_special.h(70): warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'const int' requires a narrowing conversion
1>Done building project "image.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried using CMAKE to build but that also failed.

Comment: Maybe you should show what is at line 2 of `C:\Users\Surya\Desktop\Yulio-Raytracer-master\Yulio-Raytracer-master\common\image/image.h`

Comment: Are you sure you did not accidentally edit that file? Line 2 is a comment in the git sources.